# How to schedule different push notifications for a particular user using SWIFT

Tags: ios, web-services, parse-platform, push-notification, swift2

I am wondering if it's possible to do the following:

An user can save a lot of dates, for example: the date right now is **12/02/15 09:00**, and the user saves two dates: **12/02/15 09:10** and **12/02/15 09:20**. Then he closes the app. What I want to do is send a notification for this particular user at 09:10 and another at 09:20 to remember him of something.

Is it possible? I am using swift 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not Swift, but you can get the idea from here. Hope it helps.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

[How to create multiple Local Notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698237/how-to-create-multiple-local-notifications)