# iOS local notification not firing second time but shows in getpendingnotificationrequests

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10, local, unusernotificationcenter

I have implemented iOS 10 local notification where it works for the first alarm but not for other. I have import iOS 10 library , implemented delegate , receiving it first time in the delegate but it just not firing later.

My date formate looks like : 2017-05-28 14:04:07 +0000

```
    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
    //(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute)
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:now];

   NSDate *todaySehri = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


 UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];

            objNotificationContent.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Local.."]] arguments:nil];


                  objNotificationContent.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Incoming Local Notification" arguments:nil];


            objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound soundNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",soundFileBtn.titleLabel.text]]; // [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];//soundFileBtn.titleLabel.text;// [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
            NSDictionary *dict = @{@"alarmID":self.myKey,
                                                   @"SOUND_TYPE":[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%li",(long)self.audio_segment.selectedSegmentIndex]
                                                   };
            NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:dict, nil];
            NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"payload"];


            [objNotificationContent setUserInfo:data];

            //update application icon badge number
            objNotificationContent.badge = @([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 0);

            NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

              NSDateComponents *compss= [cal components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute)
                          fromDate:todaySehri];

             UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:compss repeats:NO];

            UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:[todaySehri description]
                                                                                  content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
            //schedule localNotification
            UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
            [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
                }
            }];
```

Comment: try printing the `identifier` you are setting for each trigger to check if they are different or not. Also how are you testing the notification? By manually changing the time on the device or waiting for the time?

Comment: identifier is different in my NSLog. Even i appended an extra random string into my identifier. And I am checking the alarm on simulator. I set 3 separate alarm. And i set my macbook time near to first alarm. When it works, then again i changed my macbook time near to second alarm and run my project. But it does not work for second or other alarm. @bhakti123

Comment: Check if all the alarms are scheduled or not. And what is their next trigger date. Then try to change the timing according to that trigger date and see if it works.

Comment: What do you mean by scheduled ? How could i check it ? My compss contains the firedate of the alarm which i set to trigger. @ bhakti123

Comment: you can check the scheduled alarms by using `getpendingnotificationrequests`

Comment: I am getting the pending or not played alarm in getpendingnotificationrequests in the array :(  @ bhakti123

Comment: Yes, in that list can you see your notifications?

Comment: Yes, i see notification on correct time in my notification array . I set macbook time 2/3 minutes ago, and run, start waiting. But the time crosses, it never show alarm or call alarm firing delegate!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145220/discussion-between-bhakti123-and-jamshed-alam).

Comment: Just to be sure: is your app open/in foreground when you get the 2nd notification? Can you just try testing this with a real device?

Comment: Why would it ever need to be triggered for the 2nd time? and which line is that you're setting the notification for a 2nd time?

Comment: @honey, (1) I am trying on real device. (2) I need to triggered 2nd time because it is separate notification. Is there any way to create multiple notification in multiple time with same  triggered object or anything ?

Comment: @JamshedAlam Which method gets execute when your app is in background and you receive a Notification?

Comment: Of course i had the delegate to receive notification. I was getting first notification only. @ArgaPK

Answer (score 0):

How about setting your trigger `YES` to repeat? Also, check this out. answer for [repeating local notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022413/1421553)

Comment: NO !!
Repeating (YES) means you want to see this everyday or any certain time later. But here i am setting the notification separately for separate day. Suppose, i create 3 notification for 3 days in 3 separate time.

Comment: In that case you should keep three identifiers to separate out different notifications

Comment: Yes, my identifier is requestWithIdentifier-> [todaySehri description] which is different string in each trigger. Then what should i do ? :(